# How can I rename a name a GWT nocache.js and path?

Tags: gwt

Hello guys I am newbie in GWT. and I am getting a error nocache.js not found.
when I checked the url its showing like

> https://localhost:8643/gwt_4_chemicals/_4_ChemicalsSearchReviewDetail/_4_ChemicalsSearchReviewDetail.nocache.js

but the actual nocache path is

> https://localhost:8643/gwt_4_chemicals/_4_ChemicalsReviewSearch/_4_ChemicalsReviewSearch.nocache.js

how can I rename

```
 nocache to _4_ChemicalsSearchReviewDetail
 and folder name to  _4_ChemicalsSearchReviewDetail;
```

actually this nocache URL is used in many java file so I cant change this URL. so I have to change folder and  nocache.js...

please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name of the nocache.js in your module descriptor:

```
<module rename-to='_4_ChemicalsSearchReviewDetail'>
```

This should solve your problem.

Don't forget to change the mdoule in your running configuration.

Comment: thanks for reply but  I am not getting your point correctly which running  configuration you are taking about.

Comment: f.e.: if you are using eclipse, you have to update the GWT running configuration.

Comment: yes I am using eclipse !! could you please refer me suppose steps

Comment: I renamed as you say but nocache.js file is not renaming. please check my post question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694639/how-can-we-rename-gwt-nocache-js